# Windows text file appears corrupted on Ubuntu after USB transfer

Tags: ubuntu

I encountered something extremely strange today.

Here's what happened: I wrote a short Python script (to check the connectivity to a host) at work using PyDev. I transferred it from my Windows 7 laptop to a Ubuntu workstation via a thumb drive, and the file would appear as a bunch of gibberish. I tried re-saving and renaming the file, but that did not help. I tried viewing the file on another Ubuntu workstation, and the same thing happened. This has not affected any of my other Python files. I doubt the problem is with my thumb drive because I can read off it perfectly on the laptop.

I eventually decided to e-mail the file to myself, and that solved the problem. Does anyone know what may have happened?

Comment: "Gibberish"?  It'd help to include a sample of what you see.

Comment: I'll post a screenshot when I get to work tomorrow morning.

Comment: Strange, I made a few changes to the Python file, and it no longer appears as gibberish. Maybe a sector on the thumb drive was corrupted in a way such that it was only unreadable on Ubuntu. Who knows?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided I suspect this might have to with the difference in line endings used in *nix and Windows.  Check out [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) on Wikipedia.

You can confirm if the line ending is the causing the problem by inspecting it using an utility that can dump the ascii characters. On Ubuntu you can use `hexdump`

```
hexdump <filename>
```

And here's an example that illustrates the difference in line endings between the two systems.  The input file is a simple text file named sample.txt with the words line1 and line2 on separate lines

```
$ cat sample.txt
line1
line2
```

Output of sample.txt created on a Linux system

```
sample.txt:
00000000  6c69 6e65 310a 6c69 6e65 320a           line1.line2.
```

Output of sample.txt create on a Windows system

```
sample.txt:
00000000  6c69 6e65 310d 0a6c 696e 6532 0d0a      line1..line2..
```

To convert between the types of line-endings try [dos2unix](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) or [fromtodos](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/fromdos).